# Removing \n from myFile

Tags: python, anagram

I am trying to create a dictionary of list that the key is the anagrams and the value(list) contains all the possible words out of that anagrams.

So my dict should contain something like this

```
{'aaelnprt': ['parental', 'paternal', 'prenatal'], ailrv': ['rival']}
```

The possible words are inside a .txt file. Where every word is separated by a newline. Example

```
Sad
Dad
Fruit
Pizza
```

Which leads to a problem when I try to code it.

```
with open ("word_list.txt") as myFile:
    for word in myFile:
        if word[0] == "v": ##Interested in only word starting with "v"
            word_sorted =  ''.join(sorted(word)) ##Get the anagram
            for keys in list(dictonary.keys()):
                if keys == word_sorted: ##Heres the problem, it doesn't get inside here as theres extra characters in <word_sorted> possible "\n" due to the linebreak of myfi
                    print(word_sorted)
                    dictonary[word_sorted].append(word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *every* word in "word_list.txt" is followed by '\n' then you can just use slicing to get rid of the last char of the word.

```
word_sorted = ''.join(sorted(word[:-1]))
```

But if the last word in "word_list.txt" *isn't* followed by '\n', then you should use `rstrip()`.

```
word_sorted = ''.join(sorted(word.rstrip()))
```

The slice method is slightly more efficient, but for this application I doubt you'll notice the difference, so you might as well just play safe & use `rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rstrip()`, it removes the `\n` character.

```
...
...
keys == word_sorted.rstrip()
...
```

Comment: Q: If word_sorted has a newline, shouldn't that just be retained in the key value of the dictionary.  Sorry if it's a noob question, but why should the newline be special?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the .rstrip() function in your code, it will remove the "\n"

Here you can check it [.rstrip()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm)

Answer (score 0):

strip only removes characters from the beginning or end of a string.

- Use rstrip() to remove \n character

Also you can use replace syntax, to replace newline with something else.

str2 = str.replace("\n", "")

Answer (score 0):

So, I see a few problems here, how is anything getting into the dictionary, I see no assignments? Obviously you've only provided us a snippet, so maybe that's elsewhere.

You're also using a loop when you could be using `in` (it's more efficient, truly it is).

```
with open ("word_list.txt") as myFile:
    for word in myFile:
        if word[0] == "v": ##Interested in only word starting with "v"
            word_sorted = ''.join(sorted(word.rstrip())) ##Get the anagram
            if word_sorted in dictionary:
                print(word_sorted)
                dictionary[word_sorted].append(word)
            else:
                # The case where we don't find an anagram in our dict
                dictionary[word_sorted] = [word,]
```